# How to disallow usage of 'concise methods' using eslint

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

Check this sample code below

```
var Syntax = {

  /* eslint should throw error for this */
  concise () {
    console.log("Concise syntax (es6). No 'function' keyword.");
  },

  normal: function () {
    console.log("Normal syntax.");
  }

};
```

- Have tried setting `es6` environment to `false` & `ecmaParser` option to `5` in .eslintrc config. Still not throwing any errors
- Have went through all eslint rules available. None matching.
- I use babel-eslint as parser

Answer (score 0):

There is this eslint plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-inferred-method-name

It seems to do what you said. It claims to throw an error if you define:

```
{
    concise () { ... }
}
```

But will not throw an error if you did:

```
{
     normal: function() { ... }
}
```

To use it first install:

```
$ npm install -g eslint-plugin-no-inferred-method-name
```

and add:

```
"plugins": [
    "no-inferred-method-name"
],
```

to your eslint file.

Comment: Sorry.. tried it too, not working. Is this plugin working for you ?

Comment: The first snippet is a shorthand for the second snippet. `no-inferred-method-name` treats both as invalid, because they both don't do lexical binding of the function name inside the function itself (i.e. you can't call `concise()` inside `concise` nor can you call `normal()` inside `normal`). You can try [`object-shorthand`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand), but you can't disallow just shorthand methods, only both methods and props.